# Error C3615 with Qt 5.8 while compiling on Visual Studio 2017 Community edition

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

Today I installed qt 5.8 with msvc2015 https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.8/5.8.0/
I also obviously download and installed the qt  tools on VS and everything works just fine till now. To see if everything worked I tried to open a new project with Visual C++ ---> Qt  and then selecting Qt  GUI application. When I tried to compile and run the project I get different error messages on the qalgorithm.h header saying error C3615:  a constexpr function cannot return a const value.

What does that mean?

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59575

Comment: Thanks, I tried to replace the qalgorithm.h file with the one in the link. The C3615 errors disappeared but it still doesn't compile and gives me errors

Comment: Can you post the new errors?

Comment: Sorry if I took too long to answer. It gives me 4 errors LNK2038 LNK2019 LNK219 LNK1120 l. It also gives me a warning : no resources in ...\QtGuiApplication.qrc

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem with your qalgorithm.h file. Take a look at [this post](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59575). Also you may want to consider upgrading to Qt 5.9 which may have addressed this issue.

LNK2038: According to [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2038), this indicates a symbol mismatch. The recommended solution is to do a clean build. In Visual Studio Solution Explorer, right click on your Solution, in the pop-up menu select "Clean Solution". This will delete old compiled files. Then right click on your Solution and in the pop-up menu select Rebuild Solution. This will rebuild everything.

LNK2019 & LNK1120: This means that it can find the definition of a symbol or reference. The clean rebuild above may fix this. If not, you need to make sure that you have included a reference to all the dlls needed by each of the projects in your solution.